# Enable browser caching for RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, browser-cache

I wrote these lines in .htaccess to enable browser caching for images:

```
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

And it works. But also I need redirect requests for non-exist images to php file. I added these lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^resized/w([0-9]+|auto)/h([0-9]+|auto)/(.*) resize.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3
```

And redirect works good. But it disabled browser caching.

How I can enable browser caching for this rule?

Comment: Will [R=301] help here?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks a lot